# Axios request giving getter setter methods instead of data queried

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, vue.js, axios

I'm working with Laravel and Vue to make a single page web application. I've used Vue before to get the data from a database using a controller with no problem, but for some reason I'm now only getting a seemingly infinitely nested JS object that has getter and setter methods stored in each parent object instead of the data I queried. I've seen other people with similar issues, but the solutions that worked for them didn't work for me. For example, some people used JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data)); to get just the raw data, but this doesn't work when I attempt to store it in this.actions. Here is my index method in my ActionLogController

```
public function index($url)
{

    $companyName = explode("/", $url);

    if(Auth::check())
    {
        $company = Company::where('name', '=', strtolower($companyName[count($companyName) - 1]))->first();

        // If sortby not empty
        $sortby = "created_at";

        //assume desc (most recent)
        $sortdirection = 'desc';

        if(request()->has('sortdirection') && request()->sortdirection == 'asc')
        {
            $sortdirection = 'asc';
        }

        // if sortby is set
        if(request()->has('sortby')) 
        {
            $sortby = request()->sortby;

            switch($sortby) 
            {
                case "date":
                    $sortby = "string_date";
                break;
                case "company":
                    $sortby = "company_name";
                break;
                case "name":
                    // do nothing
                break;
                case "communication-type":
                    $sortby = "communication_type";
                break;
                case "contact":
                    // do nothing
                break;
                case "subject":
                    $sortby = "status";
                break;
                case "assigned-to":
                    $sortby = "assigned_to";
                break;
                case "action":
                    $sortby = "action_item";
                break;
                case "assigned-to":
                    $sortby = "assigned_to";
                break;
                default:
                    $sortby = 'created_at';
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if($sortdirection == 'asc') {
        return Auth::user()->actionLogs
            ->where('activity_key', '=', '1,' . $company->id)
            ->sortBy($sortby);
    }

    return Auth::user()->actionLogs
        ->where('activity_key', '=', '1,' . $company->id)
        ->sortByDesc($sortby);

}
```

This is my Vue component to get the data from the controller. I know the template code works, because it worked fine when I sent it dummy data before pulling the data from the controller.

```
<style scoped>
.action-link {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.m-b-none {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
</style>

<template>
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-sm">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><a id="sortby-date" class="action-nav" href="?sortby=date&sortdirection=desc">Date</a></th>
                <th><a id="sortby-company" class="action-nav" href="?sortby=company&sortdirection=desc">Company</a></th>
                <th><a id="sortby-name" class="action-nav" href="?sortby=name&sortdirection=desc">Name</a></th>
                <th><a id="sortby-communication-type" class="action-nav" href="?sortby=communication-type&sortdirection=desc">Communication Type</a></th>
                <th><a id="sortby-contact" class="action-nav" href="?sortby=contact&sortdirection=desc">Contact</a></th>
                <th><a id="sortby-subject" class="action-nav" href="?sortby=subject&sortdirection=desc">Subject</a></th>
                <th><a id="sortby-action" class="action-nav" href="?sortby=action&sortdirection=desc">Comment/Action Item</a></th>
                <th>Archive</th>
                <!-- check if admin?? -->
                    <th><a id="sortby-assigned-to" class="action-nav" href="?sortby=date&sortdirection=desc">Assigned To</a></th>
                <!-- /check if admin?? -->
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody v-if="actions.length > 0">
            <tr v-for="action in actions">
                <td>
                    {{ action.string_date }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ action.company_name }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ action.name }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ action.communication_type }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ action.contact }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ action.status }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ action.action_item }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" :id="'archive-' + action.id" class="archive" :name="'archive-' + action.id">
                </td>
                <td :id="'record-' + action.id" class="assigned-to">
                    {{ action.assigned_to }}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p id="add-action" style="text-align: center;">
      <button id="action-log-add" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary edit">Add Item</button>
      <button id="action-log-edit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger edit">Edit Items</button>
    </p>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            actions: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getActionLogs(location) {

            var company = location.split("/");
            company = company[company.length - 1];

            axios.get('/action-log/' + company)
                 .then(response => {

                    this.actions = response.data;                        
                    console.log(this.actions);

                 })
                 .catch(error => {
                    console.log('error! ' + error);
                 });
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getActionLogs(window.location.href);
    }
}
</script>
```

This is the output I get in the browser console

```
    {…}
​
    1: Getter & Setter
​
    2: Getter & Setter
​
    3: Getter & Setter
​
    4: Getter & Setter
​
    5: Getter & Setter
​
    6: Getter & Setter
​
    7: Getter & Setter
​
    8: Getter & Setter
​
    9: Getter & Setter
​
    10: Getter & Setter
​
    __ob__: Object { value: {…}, dep: {…}, vmCount: 0 }
​
    <prototype>: Object { … }
```

I was expecting to see the normal array of data that gets returned, but this is what shows up instead and then won't update the component with the data. I'm new to Vue, so maybe there's something really easy I missing, but I can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: What you're looking at is how Vue proxies your data to make it reactive. This is because you're using `console.log()` on a Vue instance data property. If you just want to see the data, try `console.log(response.data)` instead. Please note, **there is nothing wrong here**

Comment: That prints out the data like you were saying, but when I store response.data in this.actions it doesn't print the data I do console.log(this.actions). Doing this also doesn't cause the component to use the data I tried to store in this.actions. As far as I can tell I shouldn't have to do anything for Vue to use this to display in the component, since that's how it behaved before, but now it doesn't update the component with the data. Would I still have to change anything else about the data returned to use it properly?

Comment: I'll say it again... when you assign values to a `data` property, it is transformed to an observable so Vue can treat it reactively. I suggest you forget about trying to `console.log()` anything assigned to `this` and use the Vue Devtool browser extension to inspect your components and their data if you're having trouble rendering the response

Comment: Also, you might want to try `<tr v-for="action in actions" :key="action.id">` so Vue can react to array changes correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing up my comments above as a sort of canonical answer to this as it keeps coming up...

What you're looking at is how Vue proxies your data to make it reactive. This is because you're using `console.log()` on a Vue instance **data property**.

When you assign values to a `data` property, it is transformed to an observable so Vue can treat it reactively. I suggest you forget about trying to `console.log()` anything assigned to `this` and use the [Vue Devtools](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools) browser extension to inspect your components and their data if you're having trouble rendering the response.

Please note, **there is nothing wrong here**.

Comment: Thank you so much, this gave me a lot of insight on the concept and has helped me get a better command over what I was working on.